# Ontario HST rebate: I'm a single individual now, but I'm expecting in July. Would I receive the family rebate amounts later?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, rebate

I am a single individual now, so I'd be receiving $100 in June.  But, I'm expecting in July (will be a single mother.) Will a change in the rebate amount come for December and so on? Would I be receiving $335 then?

Answer (score 1):

Good question!

Fortunately, the Ontario Ministry of Revenue has a Frequently Asked Question that covers your case. Refer to their FAQ: [What criteria will be used to determine who is eligible for the OSTTB?](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/sttb/faq_eligibility.html#Q3).  Excerpt:

> The Canada Revenue Agency (CRA) will
>   use the information you (and your
>   spouse or common-law partner) provide
>   on your income tax return(s) (or
>   statement of world income, if
>   applicable) and your (and your spouse
>   or common-law partner's) Canada Child
>   Tax Benefit (CCTB) information, if
>   applicable, to determine your
>   eligibility for the OSTTB.
>
> **Report to CRA any changes to your status** (e.g., **births**, death,
>   marriage, separation) that happen
>   after filing your tax return. [emphasis mine]
>
> Eligibility for each of the three
>   OSTTB payments will be determined
>   independently on the specified dates
>   below:
>
> - For the June 10, 2010 payment –
>     CRA will look at your information as
>     of May 31, 2010.
> - For the December 2010 payment –
>     CRA will look at your information as
>     of November 30, 2010.
> - For the June 2011 payment –
>     CRA will look at your information as
>     of May 31, 2011.
>
> ...

So, the answer is **yes**, you will qualify for the higher rebate once you become a parent.  But, **make sure you [contact the Canada Revenue Agency](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/cntct/menu-eng.html) and report your change in status**, otherwise they might not know that you have had a child and may maintain your next transition cheque at the single individual level.